# Fixed SVG clippingPath

Tags: css, svg, clipping

I'm trying to create a fixed clipping mask using SVG. This mask has to have `position: fixed` as I want it to scroll with the browser.

I have the following HTML/SVG and SCSS:

```
<div class="table"></div>
<div class="clipping-mask">
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clipping">
                <circle cx="50%" cy="15%" r="15%" />
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../images/table.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

    clip-path: url(#clipping);
}
.clipping-mask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    svg {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

The above code correctly clips the background and only shows what is located inside the circle. The only problem is that it isn't fixed (as in CSS `position: fixed`) and thus it doesn't scroll within the browser.

[image: Preview]

Is there any way this is possible? I *need* it to be SVG because I want to transform the shape into a rectangle at a certain point.

Comment: You may need to explain what you want a little better.  It is not clear what you want the behaviour to be.

Comment: I want a fixed position SVG clipping path. I have a background image and want only part of it to be visible. I really can't explain it any better than what I posted above.

Comment: Suggestion: place `table.jpg` as an `<image>` inside SVG and use `<path d=....>` as the (circular) clipPath.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fixing the position of the `<img`> and just applying a clipping path or mask to that?  Masks and clipping paths applied to HTML elements generally work best when defined using `objectBoundingBox` coordinates.